# Выполняется два слушателя,а нужен только один!

Tags: android

Ребята,помогите!
У меня есть список в котором находится два слушателя:setOnItemClickListener и setOnItemLongClickListener. 
Проблема состоит в том, что при зажатии на каком-либо элементе списка у меня должен выполняться setOnItemLongClickListener, но выполняется два слушателя(setOnItemClickListener и setOnItemLongClickListener).
Как мне исправить данную проблему?Нужно чтобы при зажатии выполнялся только setOnItemLongClickListener.

```
public void readLobby() {
//        progressDialog.setMessage("Загрука...");
//        progressDialog.show();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        adapterList = new FirebaseListAdapter<LobbyInfo>(getActivity(), LobbyInfo.class, R.layout.lobby_list_item,
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, LobbyInfo model, int position) {
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_items);
                TextView mess = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_mess);
                ImageView lock=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.lock);

                name.setText(model.getName());

                if (model.getMessages() != 0) {
                    mess.setText("+" + String.valueOf(model.getMessages()));
                } else {
                    mess.setText("");
                }

                names.add(model.getName());
                if(!model.getPassword().isEmpty()){
                    lock.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(model.getPassword().isEmpty()){
                    lock.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        };
//        progressDialog.dismiss();
        list.setAdapter(adapterList);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView textV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_items);
                String str = textV.getText().toString();

                DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(str);
                db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        LobbyInfo lobbyInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(LobbyInfo.class);
                        if (!lobbyInfo.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
                            alertDialogLobbyPass(lobbyInfo.getPassword(), lobbyInfo.getName());
                        } else {
                            Fragment yfc = new Chat();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("tag", lobbyInfo.getName());
                            yfc.setArguments(bundle);
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, yfc, "Chat").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView textV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_items);
                String str = textV.getText().toString();
                alertChange(str);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поменяй `return false;` в `setOnItemLongClickListener` на `return true;`

Comment: помогло!Спасибо)